# Outlook 2016 Rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter, rules

would like some help here.

There is a email forwarding rule to this email address (ITsupport@xx.com) to my main inbox. For example, if John sends an email to ITsupport@xx.com, it will forwarded to me.

i would like to create a rule whereby, anything from **John** sent to **ITsupport** goes into a folder called **John**.

i am not able to create a rule because it is from ITsupport rather than John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Internet Headers of the forwarded message (open it in a separate Outlook message window and click File -> Properties). It's highly possible that you'll find John in one or more headers. In this case, just specify **with specific words in the message header** Outlook rule condition.